# Не работает скрипт для отметки всех checkbox'ов

Tags: javascript, html, c#, css, checkbox

Требуется отметить все checkboxes по нажатию на главный checkbox. Почему скрипт не работает?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>To export</th>
    </tr>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportResults", "Exporter"))
    {
     foreach(int val in collection)
     {
         <tr>
            <td>
               <input type="checkbox" value="val" id="squaredThree_exp_@val" class="squaredThree" name="toexport"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
     } 
     <tr>
         <td>
             <input type="checkbox" value="23" id="mainSquared_exp" class="mainSquared" name="toexportmain"/>
         </td>
     </tr> 
    }
<table>
```

Код скрипта, который вынесен в отдельный файл и подключён в самом начале html-страницы:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.mainSquared').click(function () { // при клике по главному чекбоксу
        if ($('input.mainSquared').attr('checked')) { // проверяем его значение
            $('.squaredThree').setAttribute('checked', true); // если чекбокс отмечен, отмечаем все чекбоксы
        } else {
            $('.squaredThree').setAttribute('checked', false); // если чекбокс не отмечен, снимаем отметку со всех чекбоксов
        }
    });
});
```

**P.S.:** А если мы хотим искать по началу id или по началу имени элемента, можно делать это так:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[name ^= "toExportMain"]').click(function () { // при клике по главному чекбоксу
        if ($('[name ^= "toExportMain"]').prop('checked')) { // проверяем его значение
            $('[id ^= "squaredThree_exp"]').prop('checked', true); // если чекбокс отмечен, отмечаем все чекбоксы
        } else {
            $('[id ^= "squaredThree_exp"]').prop('checked', false); // если чекбокс не отмечен, снимаем отметку со всех чекбоксов
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте $().prop() для изменения состояния чекбокса.

```
$('input.mainSquared').click(function () { // при клике по главному чекбоксу
    if ($('input.mainSquared').prop('checked')) { // проверяем его значение
        $('.squaredThree').prop('checked', true); // если чекбокс отмечен, отмечаем все чекбоксы
    } else {
        $('.squaredThree').prop('checked', false); // если чекбокс не отмечен, снимаем отметку со всех чекбоксов
    }
});
```

Comment: Можно покороче записать: `$('input.mainSquared').click(function () {
        $('.squaredThree').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});`

Comment: @Deonis, ага, спасибо за замечание **:)** А так я просто тупо взял поправил код.

Comment: @ ARZi, а если я хочу по id элемента искать, как тогда изменится код?

Comment: @Deonis, Спасибо за ответ. А почему-то на соседней форме выделение не работает. У меня на странице должно быть две колонки с checkbox'ами и под каждой из них checkbox для выделения всех. Тот, что левее, работает. А тот, что правее - нет. В чём причина?

Comment: Разобралась!
Чтобы искать элемент по началу id или по имени, код будет выглядеть так:

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[name ^= "toExportMain"]').click(function () { // при клике по главному чекбоксу
        if ($('[name ^= "toExportMain"]').prop('checked')) { // проверяем его значение
            $('[id ^= "squaredThree_exp"]').prop('checked', true); // если чекбокс отмечен, отмечаем все чекбоксы
        } else {
            $('[id ^= "squaredThree_exp"]').prop('checked', false); // если чекбокс не отмечен, снимаем отметку со всех чекбоксов
        }
    });
});

Comment: Вместо prop можно еще короче написать if ( $('somecheckbox').is(':checked') )

Answer (score 2):

Потому что не атрибуты надо менять, а свойства:

```
$('.squaredThree').prop('checked', true);
```

И вообще, в jQuery метод называется `attr`, а не `setAttribute`.

> http://api.jquery.com/attr/
>
> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ( $('input.mainSquared').attr('checked') ) { // проверяем его значение
        $('.squaredThree').attr('checked', true); 
    } else {
        $('.squaredThree').removeAttr('checked');
    }
```

Попробуйте удалять атрибут совсем, если снято выделение с чекбокса